# How should I handle internationalization of display strings for FHIR observations?

Tags: internationalization, hl7-fhir

I'm working on a multi-tenant application catering to customers in different countries. When displaying measurement results, the display labels measurement values need to be in different languages.

Labels for measurement values received in one tenant will only need to be translated to that tenant's language (we assume that the users will be patients or employers that understand the same language).

What is a good strategy for storing/displaying translated strings? Should I perform translation when storing the values and add a custom value in `code.coding` or is it better to translate existing `code.coding.display` values when rendering the view?

Answer (score 1):

FHIR is silent on whether you should translate before storing or when returning data.  Do consider the ramifications on digital signatures regardless of approach (anyone adding translations after the instance is signed will break the signature).  There's a standard extension for conveying the language of a string and translations of the string - see http://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-iso21090-st-language.html and http://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-iso21090-st-translation.html.  These work on *any* string in a FHIR instance.